# Bouncing Effect For Image From Top to Bottom wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, storyboard

How to Achieve Bouncing Effect to Image in wp8?Actually I want to make Animation for Bouncing Image From Top to Bottom.

I Refered Following Links

http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-add-bounce-effect-to-dynamically-created-images-in-winrt/

My Code :

```
      var sb = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, image);
        sb.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        sb.AutoReverse = true;
        var da = new DoubleAnimation();
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("Height"));
        da.From = 0;
        da.To = 500;           
        da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d);
        da.EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };
        sb.Children.Add(da);
        sb.Begin();
```

Please Any help?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Unfortunately It is not working like Bouncing from top to Bottom.Its working like just blinking Image.

Comment: You can add your solution in an answer below.  That's how it's done around here.  Congrats.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to add my Answer here.I am getting like this."We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling dependant animation:

```
da.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Jimmy ,I solved my Problem and Updated in my Question.